# Jersey/JAXB/XML/JSON: Adding elements to documents created from POJOs

Tags: xml, json, jaxb, jersey

I'm new to Jersey, JAXB, and JSON, and fairly green with XML.  I'm playing with a simple Web service (which strives to be RESTful).

Given the following POJO:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class POJO {
  .
  .
  @XmlElement
  public String getProp1 {
    return prop1;
  }

  @XmlElement
  public String getProp2 {
    return prop2;
  }
}
```

and the following resource class:

```
@Path("/resource)
public class Resource {

  @Path("/pojo")
  @GET
  @Produces({"application/xml", "application/json"})
  public POJO getPojo() {
    POJO pojo = new POJO();
    pojo.setProp1("foo");
    pojo.setProp2("bar"); 
    return pojo;
  }
}
```

HTTP requests to the proper URI return the XML and JSON I expect:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <pojo>
       <prop1>foo</prop1>
       <prop2>bar</prop2>
   </pojo>

{"prop1":"foo","prop2":"bar"}
```

Next, I want to update the service to produce the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <pojo>
       <prop1>foo</prop1>
       <prop2>bar</prop2>
       <link>http://coolURI</link>
   </pojo>

{"prop1":"foo","prop2":"bar","link":"http://coolURI"}
```

where "coolURI" is a hypermedia pointer to the next resource, and obviously not a property of    class POJO, so its value will be marshaled to XML differently.  Please point me toward the mechanism(s) I need to employ and I should be good to go.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must return something else than a POJO from your getPojo() method. Either an extended POJO that includes the link, or a Response object that somehow inserts the link.